# How can I work with paragraphs in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, paragraph

Wordpress has a filter that automatically add paragraphs to posts. I can remove this by adding the followin code:

```
// Remove the <p> tags which WP automatically inserts in psots.
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

The problem is that i removes `<br />` tags as well.

So I'm not removing this filter at the moment. My problem is that inside a DIV box, I get extra space above and below the text (at the start / end of text).

I could manipulate the `<p>` tag in css, but again, that will affect all `<p>` tags throughout the post content.

Any suggestions to what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe this would help you

```
<?php wpautop( $post, $br = 0 ); ?>
```

the second parameter is boolean and is to do with the line breaks.

[codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: So where would you place this? functions.php? or in your template where your content is being called?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing blank lines after  and before  in your post content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think @mroggle's method might work.
The last I had this issue, I had to manually throw in `<br />`s.